# On button click choose image from gallery and set in another activity's imageView

Tags: android

I have two activities in one i have a button and in second i have a ImageView, Now i want if i click on first activity's button then i go to gallery and pick an image when i select an image then it will automatically set in second activity's ImageView, My code is working when i set image in same acticity's imageView but i want set the image in second activity's ImageView. Please tell me what code i need to write in SecondActivity, **My first Activity is(Select_Image)**:-

```
public class Select_Image extends Activity {
Button button;
public static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 100;
Bitmap bitmap;
String imagePath = " ";
Uri uri;
ImageView image;
String path = " ";
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.select_image);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.select_btn);
    image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.edit_image_id);  //This is second Activity's ImageView id.
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            galleryIntent();
        }
    });
}
public void galleryIntent(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == MainActivity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY){
            }
            onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
    }
}
public  void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data){
    if (data != null) {
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), data.getData());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    uri = getImageUri(this, bitmap);
    imagePath = getRealPathFromUri(uri);
    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

private String getRealPathFromUri(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String ss = cursor.getString(column_index);
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}

private Uri getImageUri(Select_Image select_image, Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Toast.makeText(select_image, "Image uploaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(select_image.getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

}

**Second Activity(MainActivity)**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onActivityResult, you got the result which is used by your current activity. If an image is selected you got your result on onActivityResult.Here, you can pass this imageUrl in your second activity and open image in your second activity. If you have still any doubt you can ask me.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up, you want to interact with Activity A, start a task then receive the result in Activity B, it's impossible. But you can get the same behavior by 2 options:

- Start Activity B on Activity A's button clicked. In Activity B's `onCreate`, start the image selector and get the result from there.
- Start the image selector in A's button clicked, get the result and then pass the result to B using `startActivity` Intent.

Prefer the first option because it makes the code cleaner, Activity B does its own job and Activity A doesn't need to know about it. Moreover, you save some performance when serialize/deserialize the param from A to B, make the activity transition smoother